# Android: ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity error

Tags: android

I'm getting an ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord,Intent) error each time I boot up my program in the debugger. The program won't even start up! Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm very new to this environment. Let me know if you need anymore information/code to help me out.

Here is my logcat:

```
06-09 11:16:26.848: ERROR/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
06-09 11:16:26.848: ERROR/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
06-09 11:16:26.848: ERROR/vold(27): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
06-09 11:16:26.848: ERROR/vold(27): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
06-09 11:16:37.887: ERROR/MemoryHeapBase(53): error opening /dev/pmem: No such file or directory
06-09 11:16:37.887: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(53): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
06-09 11:16:37.927: ERROR/libEGL(53): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library 'libhgl.so' not found)
06-09 11:16:38.407: ERROR/libEGL(64): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library 'libhgl.so' not found)
06-09 11:16:41.358: ERROR/BatteryService(53): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/usb/online'
06-09 11:16:41.367: ERROR/BatteryService(53): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_vol'
06-09 11:16:41.367: ERROR/BatteryService(53): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_temp'
06-09 11:16:41.667: ERROR/EventHub(53): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
06-09 11:16:41.667: ERROR/EventHub(53): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
06-09 11:16:41.797: ERROR/System(53): Failure starting core service
06-09 11:16:41.797: ERROR/System(53): java.lang.SecurityException
06-09 11:16:41.797: ERROR/System(53):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
06-09 11:16:41.797: ERROR/System(53):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
06-09 11:16:41.797: ERROR/System(53):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
06-09 11:16:41.797: ERROR/System(53):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:162)
06-09 11:16:41.797: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(53): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
06-09 11:16:42.777: ERROR/LockPatternKeyguardView(53): Failed to bind to GLS while checking for account
06-09 11:16:46.557: ERROR/ActivityThread(111): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
06-09 11:16:46.577: ERROR/ActivityThread(111): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings 
06-09 11:16:49.087: ERROR/ApplicationContext(53): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/wallpaper-hints.xml
06-09 11:16:51.146: ERROR/ActivityThread(108): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
06-09 11:16:54.266: ERROR/ActivityThread(108): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
06-09 11:16:54.416: ERROR/ActivityThread(108): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
06-09 11:16:56.336: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(31): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
06-09 11:16:56.356: ERROR/MediaPlayer(53): Unable to to create media player
06-09 11:16:56.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.svgeeks.kidneytest/com.svgeeks.kidneytest.KidneyTest}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at com.svgeeks.kidneytest.KidneyTest.onCreate(KidneyTest.java:57)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
06-09 11:16:56.757: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     ... 11 more
06-09 11:16:56.876: ERROR/dalvikvm(201): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is on line 57 of KidneyTest.

The error stack complaining of a ClassCastException which is thrown when a program attempts to cast an object to a type with which it is not compatible.

It looks like you are trying to cast and EditText as something it is not.

Edit: Good tip for decoding the error stack, look for the line that says *Caused by:* This line will give you a reason for the error and the line below will show you where the error is happening and will include a line reference so you can easily find the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured out the problem with your help! I had two Views with the same ID in my XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

### yes exactly it is due to some missing id that you are not using in XML and try to initialize in your java file or somewhat keywords missing, name mismatch etc.

it is due to some widget that is not mention in XML and you are trying to get it in your layout i have experience this i was getting linear layout id , even that was not mention in XML or used in .