# Android/Eclipse: assistance with LogCat

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, trace

I am building an Android app at the moment, but it keeps crashing.

I am attempting to start an activity from an options menu. I have tried many different methods of starting the activity, but I get the same result each time at the startActivity. I have defined the activity in my Manifest file, and I can run the activity from a button, just not from onOptionsItemSelected.

The error I am receiving is an ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord,Intent) error, so I went searching and found the following question:

[Android: ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008745/android-activitythread-performlaunchactivity-error)

However, I am not after a solution to this problem.

What I would like to know is how to get my logcat error trace to display in the format shown by the asker in the link above? I can't find a "Caused By" or anything similar in my logcat, which would make debugging a whole lot simpler for me. So if anyone can tell me how to find this information in the logcat, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance, Adam.

[EDIT] Here is the LogCat output. It's just lots of information about what my phone is doing, nothing to do with the app that's actually running on the phone!

```
07-21 15:36:48.441: E/DataRouter(1825): usb connection is true
07-21 15:36:48.441: E/DataRouter(1825): InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is failure 4
07-21 15:36:50.022: E/AlarmManagerService(1986): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=0, 1342850486.300000000
07-21 15:36:50.442: E/DataRouter(1825): usb connection is true 
07-21 15:36:50.442: E/DataRouter(1825): InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is failure 4
07-21 15:36:52.446: E/DataRouter(1825): usb connection is true 
07-21 15:36:52.446: E/DataRouter(1825): InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is failure 4
07-21 15:36:54.447: E/DataRouter(1825): usb connection is true 
07-21 15:36:54.447: E/DataRouter(1825): InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is failure 4
07-21 15:36:56.447: E/DataRouter(1825): usb connection is true 
07-21 15:36:56.447: E/DataRouter(1825): InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is failure 4
07-21 15:36:58.447: E/DataRouter(1825): usb connection is true 
07-21 15:36:58.447: E/DataRouter(1825): InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is failure 4
07-21 15:36:59.996: E/AlarmManagerService(1986): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 148500.000000000
07-21 15:37:00.011: E/AlarmManagerService(1986): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 148498.243000000
07-21 15:37:00.452: E/DataRouter(1825): usb connection is true 
07-21 15:37:00.452: E/DataRouter(1825): InvokeOemRequestHookRaw usbstatus true is failure 4
07-21 15:37:02.452: E/DataRouter(1825): usb connection is true
```

Comment: you have to catch and log the exception to get the full stacktrace in logcat. what do you see in logcat?

Comment: Are you able to see the logs inside `LogCat` view? If not, please try this with the tool `adb` (in `SDK/platform-tools` folder) — `adb logcat -d`.

Comment: @axel how would I execute that code? My code is in more detail in this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589480/android-start-activity-from-options-menu). Could you please give me an example that would output the error logs that I am looking for?

Comment: @LaiVung I can see logs, but not in the same format (unfortunately I can't post an image because I need 10 reputation to do so). What I can't find is a log that says "Caused by:..." after the error occurs, and in fact I can't see any logs in the view that say "AndroidRuntime" or "ActivityThread" like there are many instances of in the link provided in the question

Comment: @Adam what do you see?  Can you copy and paste the log you are getting (just the text, not the image)?  Are you viewing the log from eclipse or ddms?  Do you have filters on?

Comment: It's strange. But you don't need to take a screenshot. Please start your app, pause at the step before it's going to crash at next step. Then clear logs by `adb logcat -c`, and do test the app, then dump the logs by `adb logcat -d`. You can attach the logs here.

Comment: @hopia I am in Eclipse, in the Java perspective, with no filters. Sure, I will edit the question. (I just realised that the formatting comes from copy and pasting the LogCat output, which I guess answers a part of my question, but I'm still unsure why I am not seeing any cause of the crash)

Comment: @LaiVung the question has been edited with the logs as you described

Comment: Thanks Adam. I think if your app crashed then there will be some logs about that. Could you please try some times again and get the logs? You can post the logs in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589480/android-start-activity-from-options-menu). Sorry I couldn't help you much about this question  :-(

Comment: @LaiVung No problems, thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the onOptionsItemSelected method in a `try { } catch (Exception ex) { Log.e("ChangeScheme", "Dead as a dodo", ex) }`? It shouldn't be needed, but sounds like it might be worth trying. Also, can you confirm that there is only one android device (emulator or physical) for adb to talk to?

Comment: @Adam - I've re-opened the question and undeleted that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you show the LogCat means,

Go to **Window->Show View->Other->Android->LogCat**. Here the whole android code debug/trace widgets are available you can simply click you can get it.

Comment: Yeah I have the LogCat visible (even the old deprecated LogCat as well) but neither of them are providing me with the information that I am looking for. When my app is debugging on my phone, I don't see any statements that look like AndroidRuntime or ActivityThread in either of the LogCat's.I tried to post an image of my LogCat but I need a reputation score of 10 before I can sorry

Comment: tried to share your image using this http://imgur.com/ and post the link in your question