# Android: start activity from options menu

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to start an activity from an options menu, but my app keeps crashing. The only error that I receive is an ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord,Intent) error in the debug window in Eclipse.

Below is the the code that I am using at the moment, but keep in mind I have tried multiple options, all of which end in the same misery, at the same piece of code - the startActivity statement (discovered by using breakpoints, since I'm not sure how to see the stack trace in the LogCat window, as described in my previous question [Android/Eclipse: assistance with LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589188/android-eclipse-assistance-with-logcat)).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.changescheme, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.changeScheme).setIntent(new Intent(this, ColourActivity.class));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    this.closeOptionsMenu();
    startActivity(item.getIntent());
    return true;
}
```

And here is the changescheme.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/changeScheme" android:title="Change Colour Scheme" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"></item>
</menu>
```

I have also tried using a switch(item.getItemId()) statement in the onOptionsItemSelected block as opposed to the menu.findItem in the onCreateOptionsMenu block, but still no luck.

I have defined the activity in my Manifest file. I can also start the activity from a regular button, and the first time the app opens on a device, the activity is started immediately after my splash screen, and I have had no problems with either of these methods.

To me this indicates that there is nothing wrong with the ColourActivity class or its associated layout file, but there is a problem with the implementation from the options menu.

I have also implemented this same method as shown above (in code) in a different app and had no problems, so I'm am really at a loss here.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide logcat. Please try…

Comment: @LaiVung Please review the link provided in the question which outlines the fact that I am unsure how to go about doing this...

Comment: `ColourActivity` is your parrent `Activity`?

Comment: Do you still get the crash if you comment out the closeOptionsMenu() line? How about if you comment out the startActivity() line? Not a joyful approach to the problem, I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem now.

It turns out the problem was not at all on the `ListActivity` class, it was in fact on the `ColourActivity` class.

I was attempting to parse a few colours in `onCreate`, but I had forgotten to include the # in one of the RGB colour strings, hence the crash!

Thanks heaps for everyone's help, Adam.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct when the website lets me do so, as my reputation is too low to mark it as a correct answer straight away

Answer (score 0):

Intent you are activating should point to some target component, which is not in your case, instead you should do following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    this.closeOptionsMenu();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ColourActivity.class);
    /*Here ActivityA is current Activity and ColourActivity is the target Activity.*/
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @jeet, but I have tried it as above with ListActivity.this (instead of just "this"), with ListActivity being the class that this code is executed from, and it doesn't work. I have also tried separating the single line in my code into 2 lines as in yours (initialising the intent on a separate line) and have also had no luck with that. Any other ideas?

Comment: I checked your code, and its working perfectly. seems some other problem, if you can post Logs, we can check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflator = getMenuInflater();
    inflator.inflate(R.menu.changescheme, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId())
         {
         case  R.id.changeScheme:
         Log.d("ChangeScheme", "Selected : ChangeScheme Option");

startActivity(new Intent(MainAcitivity.this, ColourActivity.class));

          return true;
         caseR.id.help:
          Log.d("HelpMenu", "Selected : Help Option");
          //Here put your code
          return true;


         }

    }
```

Comment: This produces exactly what I would have expected. I can see it in the log before it crashes. I even tried changing the Log.d to Log.e in the hope that I could see the log directly following this (assuming that it would be the log telling me why my app crashed), but this output was the only line that showed up in the LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.changescheme, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.changeScheme:
            //start activity here
            break;

        case R.id.help:
            //start activity here
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, have already tried this, which I stated in my question. I had no luck

Answer (score 0):

Hi adam your code seem to be perfectly fine while i am testing on my emulator, please check whether you have added the class name "ColourActivity" to your manifest file.

```
  <activity android:name="ColourActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: Yes I have, thanks, although it is ".ColourActivity" in my Mainfest